# Firebase Admin SDK Incredibly Long Query Response

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have been running into an issue with Firebase admin that I cannot seem to fix. I essentially added logging before and after my Firebase query and this query takes about 5 seconds to complete. I am checking the logs after function execution in Google Cloud Functions Log Explorer and comparing timestamp.

```
    console.log("DEBUG_TIMESTAMP_FUNCTION_START");
    // ... function logic.

    console.log("DEBUG_TIMESTAMP_1");
    const userRecords = await admin.firestore().collection("UserMetaData").get().then((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    console.log("DEBUG_TIMESTAMP_2");
    // ... function logic.
    console.log("DEBUG_TIMESTAMP_FUNCTION_END");
```

This collection is **NOT** big, the entire dataset is 457 records. As you can see I am not adding any sort of filtering but this feels like its taking orders of magnitude more time than it should.

I do not think is network related as the logging I am doing is inside my Google Cloud Function. Both my Cloud Function and my Firestore instance are located in us-central.

I also do not think it is related to the cold start of the function because if I add this exact same query a second time right after the first one in the code, it doubles the response time to 10 second, and if I log 3 times (start, middle, end) it shows 5 seconds for each query.

I have no composite indexes on my Firestore Database, but I do have the "Automatic" settings left at default.

Lastly I do not think this is a document size issue, I have about 15 text fields and the total payload of all 457 records is 0.25mb.

I feel like I must be missing something very obvious and problematic.

Google Cloud Function using Node 18, and "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0"

Comment: Please edit the question to show a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example), including how you are timing this code.  We should be able to copy and paste what you have to do the same thing and observe the same results.

Comment: Updated to show how I am logging, this and the network tab in chrome. The main reason I believe it to be Firestore query specifically is adding the same request multiple times increase the network response time proportionally. i.e each time I add this query in my code 5 seconds are added to my network response time.

Comment: If you limit the query to 10 documents for example, does it take the same amount of time? Please respond using @AlexMamo